# Google Drive API - Bulk Uploader, File Renaming and Timeouts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I recently found a great google script which allows one to use Google Sheets to list lots of downloads (Jpegs in my case) and set titles. The script transloads(?)... moves the files from a remote place to your Google Drive. So no pointless downloading, uploading in-between.

```
function SaveToGoogleDrive(){

  var folderID = 'FOLDER_HERE';  // put id of the Google Drive folder
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID)// get the folder
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    var pdfURL = data[i][2];
    var myFileName = data[i][1] + '.pdf';
    var file = UrlFetchApp.fetch(pdfURL);
    folder.createFile(myFileName,file);
  }
}
```

(code comes via - http://unexpectedweb.blogspot.com.es/2017/11/directly-save-file-to-google-drive-by.html )

1. The script should allow me to set a name for each upload, which will be applied to the file on adding to Google Drive, but this doesn't work for me.

   Is there something obvious in the code which doesn't look good to you as renaming doesn't work. Perhaps there's a script that will allow me to rename once the files are all in my Google Drive?
2. Also- I'm transloading(?) about 500 files and Google's Scripts can only run for 6mins. How would I incorporate something like the script [demonstrated here:](https://ctrlq.org/code/20016-maximum-execution-time-limit)

That code...

```
/* Based on https://gist.github.com/erickoledadevrel/91d3795949e158ab9830 */
function isTimeUp_(start) {
  var now = new Date();
  return now.getTime() - start.getTime() > 300000; // 5 minutes
}

function SaveToGoogleDrive(){

  var folderID = 'FOLDER_HERE';  // put id of the Google Drive folder
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID)// get the folder
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  
  var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0, 50);  
  var start = new Date();
  
  for (var i in threads) {
    if (isTimeUp_(start)) {
      Logger.log("Time up");
      break;
    }
    
    // Process the thread otherwise    
    for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
      var pdfURL = data[i][2];
      var myFileName = data[i][1] + '.pdf';
      var file = UrlFetchApp.fetch(pdfURL);
      folder.createFile(myFileName, file);
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks for your thoughts. Having so much trouble marrying the two together with my limited knowledge.

Comment: As a point of reference, if you consider time up to be 300 seconds, your code has no reliable chance to gracefully exit. My preferred duration is about 200-275, depending on the time the resumable loop requires.

Comment: To pick up where you left off, you have to save where you were. You have 3 ways to do this: write a loop index to PropertiesService, write a loop index to CacheService, or mark processed inputs in your datasource. For example, perhaps after every 5 uploaded files, you write `"done"` in the cell next to the files you just uploaded, or you delete those rows from the input spreadsheet, etc. Also, Gmail code? you don't use `threads` at all.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
folder.createFile(myFileName,file);
```

to

```
 folder.createFile(file).setName(myFileName);
```